# JavaScript split but keep last character in succinct way

Tags: javascript

I have a string that may or may not have a period and if it does I want to split on that and then add the period back. This is the code I have

```
let blurb = body.split('.')[0];
if (blurb.length > 1) {
    blurb = blurb + '.';
}
```

I was hoping there is a more succinct and clear way to do this.

Comment: I mean, you could use the `?:` construct to make it one line, but why not just leave it as is? It’s readable and understandable.

Comment: It's 3 lines of actual code, two if you decide to collapse the line breaks. I'm not sure how much more succinct you need it to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to add it back without doing anything else...

```
let blurb = body.split('.').join('.');
```

But this is a no-op. Here's an obtuse version of your code, which may help clarify some things..

```
var  body = "Some sentences. In a paragraph.",
     bodySplit = body.split('.'),  // ["Some sentences"," In a paragraph", ""],
     firstSentence = bodySplit[0],
     firstSentenceHasChars = firstSentence.length > 1,
     blurb = null;

if (firstSentenceHasChars) {
  blurb = firstSentence + ".";
} else {
  // ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't everyone's cup of tea, but I went the regex route.  This might make you ill though:

```js
var str   = 'blah.blah';
var reg = /([a-z]+)(.?)([a-z]*)/;
var arr = str.replace(reg, "$1,$3,$2").split(",").filter(s => s);
console.log(arr);
 
str   = 'blahblah';
arr = str.replace(reg, "$1,$3,$2").split(",").filter(s => s);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with number of desired match in output as second parameter ( second parameter in split specifies number of splited element desired in output in our case you can add as 1 ).

```js
console.log( 'blah.blah'.split('.', 1)[0] + '.' )
console.log( 'blahblah'.split('.', 1)[0] + '.' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a regex. You simply replace a dot followed by anything by a dot.

```js
const dot = str => str.replace(/\..*$/, '.');

console.log(dot('hello. world'));
console.log(dot('bye bye.'));
console.log(dot('no dot here'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you want to go with this but I'd do:

```
"hohohosdsaeqwewe.kekekekekeke".replace(/([^.]*)\.([^.]*)/gi,(m,g1)=>g1+".")
```

if the sentence does not have any match, returns itself, if it does, then takes the first part(before the dot) and adds the dot back.